# Finding the area of a rectangle in python

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, python

Q: Standard input consists of exactly four integers, first x1 and y1, the coordinates of the bottom-left corner of a rectangle, then x2 and y2, the coordinates of the top-right corner.
Write a Python script named area-of-rectangle.py which outputs the rectangle’s area.

I'm SO stuck and have no clue what I'm doing. I wrote this

x1 = int(input())
y1 = int(input())
x2 = int(input())
y2 = int(input())
bottom_left = (x1 + y1)
top_right = (x2 + y2)
area = bottom_left * top_right
print(area)

IT'S ALWAYS WRONG. Please help :(

Comment: The oriented area would be `(x2-x1)*(y2-y1)`, the area would be the absolute value of that `abs((x2-x1)*(y2-y1))`. Ask/search in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Coding questions are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the area of a rectangle on a coordinate system, you need the length between x1 and x2, and the length between y1 and y2.

```
x1 = int(input())
y1 = int(input())
x2 = int(input())
y2 = int(input())

xDiff = abs(x1 - x2) # Using absolute value to ignore negatives
yDiff = abs(y1 - y2)

area = xDiff * yDiff
```

Edit: Forgot to mention, if x2 is always greater than x1, and y2 is always greater than y1, instead you can just use `xDiff = x2 - x1` and `yDiff = y2 - y1`

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER SCIENCE @SE. Please [do not answer off-topic questions: Answer well-asked questions](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).